# Transformar o eixo y em porcentagem

Tags: r, ggplot2

Boa tarde,

Tenho o seguinte comando que gera o gráfico a seguir:

```
CANDIDATOS_2018_LEGISLATIVO %>%

  group_by(DS_ESTADO_CIVIL, DS_GENERO) %>% 

  count() %>% 

  ggplot(., aes(x = reorder(DS_ESTADO_CIVIL, -n), y = n,  fill = 
DS_GENERO)) +

geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +

theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, size = 7))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu objetivo é tranformar o eixo y em valores percentuais, alguém saberia qual comando necessário?

Answer (score 1):

Para adicionar porcentagem ao eixo y, basta modificar a sintaxe como abaixo:

```
CANDIDATOS_2018_LEGISLATIVO %>% 

  group_by(DS_ESTADO_CIVIL, DS_GENERO) %>% 

  count() %>% 

  ggplot(., aes(x = reorder(DS_ESTADO_CIVIL, -n), y = n/sum(n)*100, fill 
= DS_GENERO)) +

geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +

theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, size = 7))
```